# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Model' to return type 'Model'

Tags: swift

I' facing an error while implementing a generic class with generic function. Below is the error detail:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'Model' to return type 'Model'
```

**Below is my Generic class:**

```
public class URLCacheAdapter<Model>:LoaderProtocol{

    public let adaptee:URLCache
    public let mapper: (Data,URLResponse) throws -> Model
    
    public typealias Mapper = (Data,URLResponse) throws -> Model
    
    public init(adaptee: URLCache,
                mapper: @escaping (Data,URLResponse) throws -> Model) {
        self.adaptee = adaptee
        self.mapper = mapper
    }
    
    public enum CacheErrors:Swift.Error{
        case dataNotFound
    }
    
    public func load<Model>() async throws -> Model {
        guard let cachedResponse = adaptee.cachedResponse(for: requet) else{
            throw CacheErrors.dataNotFound
        }
        return mapper(cachedResponse.data,cachedResponse.response) // Error here
    }
}
```

**Protocol:**

```
public protocol LoaderProtocol{
    func load<T>() async throws -> T
}
```

**Generic Mapper:**

```
public class DataMapper{

    public enum Errors: Error{
        case invalidData
    }

    public static func map(_ data:Data,from response:HTTPURLResponse) throws -> People{
        guard response.statusCode == 200, let root = try? JSONDecoder().decode(PeopleModel.self, from: data) else{
            throw Errors.invalidData
        }
        return ConvertModelToDto.convertToPeopleData(model: root)
    }
}
```

Can anyone help in understanding this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In your class `URLCacheAdapter` you have a generic type `Model`

```
class URLCacheAdapter<Model>:LoaderProtocol
```

In the function `load` you also have a generic type `Model`

```
func load<Model>()
```

They have the same name but are not the same types.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class URLCacheAdapter<Model>:LoaderProtocol{
```

This creates a type-parameter called Model that specializes URLCacheAdapter.

```
    public func load<Model>() async throws -> Model {
```

This creates a completely unrelated type-parameter called Model that specializes `load()`, and is the type that `load()` promises to return. It is chosen by the caller and is, I stress, completely unrelated to `URLCacheAdapter.Model`.

```
public protocol LoaderProtocol{
    func load<T>() async throws -> T
}
```

This protocol says that all conforming types implement a method `load()` which will return a type selected by **the caller**, not matter what type that is, or throw. This is generally not what you mean. What you likely meant was:

```
public protocol LoaderProtocol{
    associatedtype T
    func load() async throws -> T
}
```

This protocol requires that `load()` return a type selected by **the implementation**. That said, trying to create such a protocol is usually an indication of a [very common design mistake](https://robnapier.net/start-with-a-protocol). The general mistake here is that you likely don't want URLCacheAdapter at all. You want to conform the Model type to some Fetchable (or Cacheable, or similar) protocol. The correct design depends on exactly what you're trying to do here. But see the link above. It covers a particularly common form of this question.